# Finding and visualizing 1 lag autocorrelation for large amount of variables at once in R

Tags: r, stock, autocorrelation

So I have a rather large dataset for Stock returns. Specifically it contains 4 columns, One with the Stock name, date, returns, and lagged returns. What I would like is to somehow illustrate how many of the Stocks that is autocorrelated with the 1-lagged return. It is especially difficult as my data contains about 20k Stocks and 227k observations. Any suggestions? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could provide us with an example?

Comment: Would be happy to :) but what exactly do you want an example of?

Comment: code, data and expected outcome.

Comment: https://imgur.com/yKZ7ESR here is a screenshot of some of the data. Permno is the stock identification, and it's the autocorrelation between the ret_excess and the lagged ret_excess I want to look at. I don't have any code as I don't even know where to start tbh.  For outcome I was hoping for either like a table showing how many had a significant AC and how many does not (for example by using the ACF or some other test for AC) or maybe a graph like a histogram showing the individual test values for an AC test.